# What is iat-mode at the end of obfs4's bridge lines?

Tags: bridge, obfs4

By looking at a obfs4 bridge, we can see that it ends with `iat-mode=x` which `x` can be 0, 1 or 2.

```
Bridge obfs4 1.2.3.4:9443 0F2C3218 cert=FH+9dukjekdfhcn iat-mode=0
```

What does this `iat-mode` indicates about a bridge?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the code that Andrei posted, it seems that 0 means IAT obfuscation is off, 1 means it is enabled, and 2 is paranoid.

A [random paper I found](https://journalofcloudcomputing.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13677-021-00244-8) says IAT stands for "Inter-Arrival Time", [another random website I found](https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/evaluating-computer-network-packet-inter/35848) says IAT is "The amount of time that elapses after the receipt of a packet until the next packet arrives"

---

Of course, all of that still doesn't say much, so I asked #tor-dev(elopers). Arma confirmed it was Inter-arrival Time and said:

> it slightly rearranges the timing between groups of bytes it sends, in hopes of messing up timing signatures based on the underlying protocol that obfs4 is obfuscating.
> it might do something. it might not. more research is required, to make one that we can say something more specific about

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4/blob/obfs4proxy-0.0.9/transports/obfs4/obfs4.go#L521

```
if conn.iatMode != iatNone {
    var iatFrame [framing.MaximumSegmentLength]byte
    for frameBuf.Len() > 0 {
        iatWrLen := 0

        switch conn.iatMode {
        case iatEnabled:
            // Standard (ScrambleSuit-style) IAT obfuscation optimizes for
            // bulk transport and will write ~MTU sized frames when
            // possible.
            iatWrLen, err = frameBuf.Read(iatFrame[:])

        case iatParanoid:
            // Paranoid IAT obfuscation throws performance out of the
            // window and will sample the length distribution every time a
            // write is scheduled.
            targetLen := conn.lenDist.Sample()
            if frameBuf.Len() < targetLen {
                // There's not enough data buffered for the target write,
                // so padding must be inserted.
                if err = conn.padBurst(&frameBuf, targetLen); err != nil {
                    return 0, err
                }
                if frameBuf.Len() != targetLen {
                    // Ugh, padding came out to a value that required more
                    // than one frame, this is relatively unlikely so just
                    // resample since there's enough data to ensure that
                    // the next sample will be written.
                    continue
                }
            }
            iatWrLen, err = frameBuf.Read(iatFrame[:targetLen])
        }
```

Comment: Could you please describe what that part of the source code does? I guess not everyone is familiar with reading code and could benefit from an explanation.